# What is the difference between write and writeInt?

Tags: java

When writing to a file using an `OuputStream`, what is the difference between using `writeInt()`:

```
public static void makeFile(String name) throws Exception{
    try (
        OutputStream ostr = new FileOutputStream(name);  ) {

        //Uses writeInt() method
        ostr.writeInt(1);

        ostr.close();
    }
 }
```

and using `write()`:

```
 public static void makeFile(String name) throws Exception{
    try (
        OutputStream ostr = new FileOutputStream(name);  ) {

        // Uses the write() method with an int as input
        ostr.write(1);

        ostr.close();
    }
}
```

What do both methods mean?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc? That is thoughtfully provided for that purpose? And do you have a cogent reason for asking questions about invalid code?

Answer (score 0):

`writeInt` is not a member of `OutputStream`, so it wont compile. Assuming you use `DataOutputStream` or similar it will write the four bytes of the 32-bit integer in big-endian order. `write` will just write a single byte (the least significant of the `int`).

Arguably it wasn't a great idea to mix these two different ideas in the same interface. `DataOutputStream` should not have extended `OutputStream`, but too late to fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

writeInt(int) comes from DataOutput interface. (ObjectOutputStream implements ObjectOutput interface, and ObjectOutput interface extends DataOutput interface.) As you can see from the JavaDoc documentation for DataOutput writeInt method, it writes four bytes in big endian order to the underlying stream.

write(int) comes from OutputStream class, which is extended by ObjectOutputStream. This method writes the low order byte of the int argument (the "right most" eight bits). Again, you can see this in the JavaDoc documentation.